# How to delete item from listView using alertDialog

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, onclick

I have a ListView showing the names of different profiles, when the user holds the click on an item the activity shows an alertDialog, if the user press the confirm button I want to remove the element from my listView, from my ArrayAdapter and from my ArrayList.
I know that arg2 in the onItemLongClick method represent the index of the selected item but I want to be able to access it inside the onClick method of the positive button.
Any advice?
My ArrayList is called "ListaUtentiStringa", the ArrayAdapter is "profilesAdapter" and the listView is called listview.
Sorry for my bad english.

```
listview.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {


        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setCancelable(true);
        builder.setTitle("Vuoi davvero cancellare il profilo?");
        builder.setPositiveButton("Si", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                          // How to remove the selected item?
                            }

                        });

builder.setNegativeButton("Annulla", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        }

        });

        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
        profilesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


    return true;
    }
    });
```

Comment: you can pass the position of your item to your alert dialog , if user presses on delete button then you just have to remove the item at that position !!

Comment: How can I pass the position? I can't pass arg2

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this..

Use `ListaUtentiStringa` `ArrayList` and `profilesAdapter` `adapter` as **Global variable**.

```
 builder.setPositiveButton("Si", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                      // How to remove the selected item?

                                ListaUtentiStringa.remove(arg2);
                                profilesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                dialog.dismiss();
                        }

                    });
```

**EDIT**

```
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, final int arg2, long arg3) {
```

Comment: But I can't refer to arg2 because "Cannot refer to a non-final variable arg2 inside an inner class defined in a different method"

Comment: @Moltehh Use `View arg1,final int arg2, long arg3`

Comment: I get this error if I try using arg2 ("Cannot refer to a non-final variable arg2 inside an inner class defined in a different method")

Comment: Just saw your edit; no compilation errors now, maybe it works. Thanks!

Comment: Global variables are a poor way to share state between components in an Android app.  You should not do that.

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
   listview.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {


@Override
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
              final int position, long id) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setCancelable(true);
        builder.setTitle("Vuoi davvero cancellare il profilo?");
        builder.setPositiveButton("Si", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
         // How to remove the selected item?
          adapter.remove(adapter.getItem(position));
        }

    });
```

Comment: I can't make a reference to the position variable, I wrote the error I get in one of the comments